# Storing primary keys as JSON strings

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have a use case where we want to associate multiple values as a partition key of a ddb record, hence we are considering storing them as a JSON string as below:

| BillingRecordId | BillingRecordType | TransactionId | TransactionPeriod | SKU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"transactionId":"100787","groupId":1,"isGrouped":true} | Regular | 10509091 | MAY-2023 | SKU-123 |

The issue is that each such billing record can be either “grouped” or “non-grouped”. If its “grouped”, then we will have an associated “groupId” with each such record, else it will not be present.

We are considering below approaches:

1. Store “isGrouped” boolean as part of partition key. Also store group id. In this case, the BillingRecordId would be of format:

   ```json
   {"transactionId":"10509091","groupId":1,"isGrouped":true}
   {"transactionId":"10509091","groupId":null,"isGrouped":false}
   ```
2. Instead of using a JSON serialized string, we will create a concatenated partition key of the format `<transactionId>.<groupId>` or just `<transactionId>` (depending on if its grouped or not)

   ```
   10509091
   10509091.1
   ```
3. Keep groupId itself as nullable. Alternatively, we can keep groupId as a json list [].

   ```json
   {"transactionId":"10509091","groupId":null}
   {"transactionId":"10509091","groupId":[]}
   ```

Queries:

- Are there any cons of using such an approach of using JSON strings as partition key?
- Are there any other high level approaches which help handle missing attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the JSON value as the partition key, but it's not flexible because whenever you want to filter records, you have to form the JSON object, which is unnecessary.

Instead of saving the JSON string as the partition key, consider using the transaction_id alone as the primary key and use the group_id(s) attribute as a sort key. The sort key complements the partition key to identify unique records in the database.

This approach allows you to avoid saving JSON objects in the database, improving data readability and reducing the size of records in the DynamoDB table.